# Alternative way to Reset to Original Pose

Tags: pose-mode

I just started weight painting
And have been rotating alot 
I dont want to manually rotate it back

I know that you can just use Alt+R

But theres a problem it brings up AMD Settings

I dont have a PC of my own
So ive been working in this project in
A Internet Cafe

Is there an option to press on the Menu?

Comment: did you try pressing spacebar to bring up the search menu then search for "Clear Rotation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your bone selected go into the pose menu and clear the transform on rotation. See pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

or you can do it like this in Blender 2.8

Pose >> Clear Transform >> All